# Soundcloud API - Extracting tracks reposted by a user

Tags: api, soundcloud

As reposts where introduced in the new soundcloud website, is it also possible to extract tracks reposted by a given user through the API ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API endpoints which give you reposts are not yet part of the public API. The only reason for this is that we haven't yet fully decided on a format and so on -- basically, once it's part of the documented API, then we have a complete responsibility never to break that backwards compatibility, and we can't quite promise that yet.

Comment: Hi Nick, Is there any way to subscribe to a feed or something where it's possible to be aware of when you update the public API, and which updates there have been made available?

Comment: Hey Kasper: follow [@SoundCloudAPI](https://twitter.com/SoundCloudAPI) on twitter, and any developments should be broadcast there.

Comment: Is there a estimated date when you will publish this feature? I am very looking forward to it.

Comment: This API is kind of useless without including reposts

Comment: None of the Twitter accounts gives visibility or answer on that question. @nickf, could you tell us if SoundCloud has planned to implement that feature in a near future?

Comment: Sorry, but no. No ETA, either.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a technical issue. Souncloud could benefit from business decision transparency.

Answer (score 11):

Replace User Id, limit and offset with what you need:

*Updated:*

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/stream/users/<userId>/reposts?limit=50&offset=0
```

*Old answer:*

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/profile/soundcloud:users:<userId>?limit=50&offset=0
```