# Reposting a track via the SoundCloud API

Tags: soundcloud

"Liking" a track seems easy enough; `PUT` to `/me/favorites/<track ID>`. But I don't see any way to repost a track in the API documentation; am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you want to (legally) repost a track?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "legally"; I'm referring to the functionality accessible by the "Repost" button in the web UI, which shares a track through your stream to anyone following you.

Comment: So you don't mean "upload someone else's content as your own".

Comment: Correct, I'm not talking about uploading at all.

Answer (score 4):

Doing a little digging, it seems the web UI uses `PUT` to `/me/track_reposts/<track ID>`, but this resource isn't documented in the API docs (yet?). I guess this is because SoundCloud doesn't want to support this API yet?

Comment: (Leaving this here for now in hopes of an official response from SoundCloud)

Comment: right now the correct end-point is ```/e1/me/track_resposts/<track ID>```  will probably change again in the future.   You can simple do "inspect element" and then look under network when you repost for the correct API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it doesn't seem to be supported yet. I have my fingers crossed for sometime soon - it would make the API significantly more useful.

From this post:
[Soundcloud API - Extracting tracks reposted by a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914059/soundcloud-api-extracting-tracks-reposted-by-a-user)

> "The API endpoints which give you reposts are not yet part of the public API. The only reason for this is that we haven't yet fully decided on a format and so on -- basically, once it's part of the documented API, then we have a complete responsibility never to break that backwards compatibility, and we can't quite promise that yet."

Answer (score 0):

`/e1/me/track_reposts/<track ID>` works currently :)