# How to get reposted tracks from my activities?

Tags: api, soundcloud

Using the Souncloud API, I'd like to retrieve the reposted tracks from my activities. The `/me/activities` endpoint seems suited for this and I tried the different types provided.

However, I didn't find out how to get that data. Does anyone know?

Comment: could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914059/soundcloud-api-extracting-tracks-reposted-by-a-user

Comment: The link pointed out by @UğurÖzpınar in the above comment led to answer that it is not possible, at the moment, to get reposted tracks from the SoundCloud public API. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Replace User Id, limit and offset with what you need:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/profile/soundcloud:users:41691970?limit=50&offset=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach:

1. Get the users that shared a track via `/tracks/{id}/shared-to/users` endpoint.
2. Fetch the tracks postet by this user via `/tracks` endpoint, as the _user_id_ is contained.
3. Compare the tracks metadata with the one you originally posted.

I am not into the Soundcloud API, but taking a close look at it seems to make this approach at least as technical possible, though e.g. fetching all tracks won't be a production solution, of course. It's more a hint. Perhaps reposting means something totally different in this context.

And the specified entpoint exists in the [general api doc](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users), so I don't know if you would have to extend the java-api-wrapper for using it.